# Issue converting vector to string in c

Tags: c

I am trying to convert a vector into a string using the following function.

```
char* my_vect2str(char** input)
{
    int i;
    char* ret = (char*)xmalloc(sizeof(char*));
    for(i=0; input[i] != NULL; i++)
    {
        if(*input[i] == '\0')
            ret[i] = ' ';
        else
            ret[i] = *input[i];
    }
    ret[i] = '\0';
    return ret;
}
```

This appears to be getting just the first character of each string in the vector. How do I alter my for loop to get this working properly? Thanks!

Comment: You're only looping over each string in the vector and looking at its first character. Seems like you want an inner loop also.

Comment: ... and it seems you need more than `sizeof char*` space for the result. BTW: you actually need two loops: one to sum the total length, and one to perform the concatenation (or: you have to realloc at least once)

Answer (score 0):

Your malloc should be the size of the pointer contents, not the pointer itself. You also don't need to cast the malloc void *. You need an inner loop counter in order to iterate through both dimensions of you pointer. This should work:

```
char* my_vect2str(char** input)
{
    int i;
    int count = 0;
    char* ret = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*)); // should be a larger size
    for(i=0; input[i] != NULL; i++)
    {
        int j = 0;
        while(1){
            if(input[i][j] == '\0'){
                ret[count++] = ' ';
                break;
            }else{
                ret[count++] = input[i][j];
            }
            j++;
        }
    }
    ret[count] = '\0';
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: the line: for(j = 0; input[i][j] != NULL; j++){

is giving the error that it is a comparison between a pointer and an integer

Comment: Sorry about that, I was comparing a char to null-value, it should work now.

Comment: what is while(true)? true is undeclared

Comment: `true` is defined in `<stdbool.h>` (in C99 or C11).

Comment: this is fairly close as it now prints a string of the correct length. But instead of printing each letter of the string it prints the first letter the length of each word. For instance: vector: "test string" outputs "tttt ssssss"

Comment: Just noticed that @user132490, it should be fixed now: changed ret[count++] = *input[i] to input[i][j].

Answer (score 0):

The first loop calculates the total size of the strings in input.  Then, the space is allocated and the strings are concatenated to ret.

```
char* my_vect2str(char** input)
{
    int i, j, k = 0;
    char* ret;
    int size = 0;
    int len;
    char* inp = input[k++];

    while (inp != NULL) {
        size += strlen(inp);
        inp = input[k++];
    }

    ret = malloc((size * sizeof(char)) + 1);
    memset(ret, 0, size + 1);

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    while (i < size) {
        if (input[j] != NULL) {
            len = strlen(input[j]);
            memcpy(&ret[i], input[j], len);
            i += len;
        }
        ++j;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: `char *inp = input;` What type of data does inp point at? What type of data does input point at? What kind of data does strlen expect inp to point at?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] before too long.  You need to be careful when submitting code.  It is a good idea to make sure it compiles (without compiler warnings) and works as intended.  Your code has a problem in the line `char *inp = input;`.  Also, would it be simpler to use `strcpy()` or even `memmove()` to copy the data into the target array?

Comment: You are both, of course, correct.  I have changed by answer and I am sorry for my arrogance.  I was so excited to start here that I got far too ahead of myself.